# plotting frequency of domain visits

Tags: r

I have a .csv file whose rows are just lists of domains I've visited, e.g. google.com, en.wikipedia.org, xkcd.com. I'd like to use R to plot the most frequently visited domains on a chart.

So far I have set domains to be the .csv file, and used `sort(table(domains)[table(domains)>=24])` and got this:

```
    domains
               twitter.com    threewordphrase.com 
                        25                     36 
    blackboard.bowdoin.edu               xkcd.com 
                        37                    187 
                google.com       en.wikipedia.org 
                       196                    229
```

I plot with `plot(sort(table(domains)[table(domains)>=24]))` and I get a scatterplot with the visits on the y axis, and the index number of the websites on the x axis, i.e. 1, 2, 3.... What I really want is the domain names on the x-axis. Any tips? I would post an image but I don't have any points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've got factors, rather than character strings. Try, when you're converting it into a table, adding stringsAsFactors = FALSE as an additional parameter: see if that clears things up.